# Show columns of current year and previous year in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to show in oracle customers rated by a particular grade for current year and previous year. E.g. the columns are Grade, Customers Rated with the particular grade for the current year,  Customers Rated with the particular grade for the previous year. The Grade should be as group and the customers should show total. If there are no customers then is should print 0.
[image]

The Above screenshot is the expected output. Until now I have only the Current Year Customers which are > 01/01/2016. I cannot create a query to bring also the Previous Year Customers.

My current year for customers query is:

`SELECT Rating
, count(customers) as Curr_year_Custs
from Rated_Customers
where Rated_year > = '2016'
group by Rating;`

Comment: You are not new to this site, so I don't really have to tell you that this is not enough information! Please edit your question with table structure, data and expected output.

Comment: @sagi should I add more information on this question?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected output out of what input?...

Comment: Well the input is a join query that brings the current year's customers totals of the particular grade.

Comment: And you should post that data so we will understand how you got to the results.

Comment: Is the last Edit helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT grade,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE '2015-01-01' >= date_column
                             AND date_column < DATE '2016-01-01'
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_2015,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE '2016-01-01' >= date_column
                             AND date_column < DATE '2017-01-01'
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_2016
FROM   Customers
WHERE  Date_Column >= DATE '2015-01-01'
AND    Date_Column <  DATE '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY grade;
```

Comment: Hi @MTO thanks a lot for the feedback it works. Don't understand though why do you put the 'where' at the end of the main query?

Comment: If you have an appropriate index then you can filter the result set to only consider those rows which are between the ranges you are interested in. If you don't have the `WHERE` clause then your query may consider rows going back multiple years which are outside the scope of your requirements and will just cause unnecessary work for the database.