# Birt Report and Date Parameter between current year and previous year

Tags: oracle, date, birt

I am using the following query that was suggested to me by a fellow from stackoverflow. The following query is using the dates in order to bring the current year (>2016,<2017) and the previous year (>2015, <2016). I want to use this in a Birt report - and particularly prompt the user to select the date (by default the current date will be selected) and automatically the query will subtract a year in order to calculate the current year's results and the previous year's results. [Here's the code given to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174238/show-columns-of-current-year-and-previous-year-in-oracle)

```
SELECT grade,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE '2015-01-01' >= date_column
                             AND date_column < DATE '2016-01-01'
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_2015,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE '2016-01-01' >= date_column
                             AND date_column < DATE '2017-01-01'
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_2016
FROM   Customers
WHERE  Date_Column >= DATE '2015-01-01'
AND    Date_Column <  DATE '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY grade;
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this in the birt report?

Comment: The question is tagged as "oracle", but the SQL syntax is not Oracle SQL!?

Comment: But it works on my Oracle environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179149/birt-report-multiple-parameters-for-the-same-field/36181862#36181862) to see how to add parameters to a SQL query in Birt. You should add your Report Parameter to input the date from the user first.

To substract a year from the input parameter you should use [DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) with a negative value for one year inside your SQL query where you add the parameter.

your query should look like this for the Input-Parameter date `2016-01-01`:

```
SELECT grade,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, -1, ?) >= date_column
                             AND date_column < ?
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_last_year,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN ? >= date_column
                             AND date_column < DATEADD(year, 1, ?)
                            THEN customer_id END
            ) AS number_of_unique_customers_in_current_year
FROM   Customers
WHERE  Date_Column >= DATEADD(year, -1, ?)
AND    Date_Column <  DATEADD(year, 1, ?)
GROUP BY grade;
```

Comment: Your answer helps but there's a limit between the years right? I mean in the above query example I want the user to select a year e.g. 2018 so that I can show the results for any current year, in this case current 2018, and last year 2017. Let me know if this is a more narrative answer.

Comment: From what I can understand the above query is limited for the years 2015 and 2016 right? If yes then how can I make it in order to work for individual years?

Comment: you must replace the occurence of `'2015-01-01'` and `'2016-01-01'` in your query with `?` to use parameters in your query. You can use them where ever you want, they are not limited to the where-clause.